# Unique index in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone please help me with creation of unique index @ mongoDB for the following condition ?

Suppose I have a schema like this, and I want a unique compound index on 1.path 2.verb 3."switches.name" 4."switches.value"

```
{
  "path": "somepath",
  "verb": "GET",
  "switches": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "value":"123"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "value":"25"
    }
  ]
}
```

So if I try to insert

```
{
  "path": "somepath",
  "verb": "GET",
  "switches": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "value":"123"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "value":"25"
    }
  ]
}
```

I should get duplicate error, but if I insert

```
{
  "path": "somepath",
  "verb": "GET",
  "switches": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "value":"123"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "value":"24"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "path": "somepath",
  "verb": "GET",
  "switches": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "value":"123"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "value":"25"
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "value":"bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I shouldn't get any error.

Basically, I should be allowed to insert documents with distinct array "switches".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid what you want to achieve cannot be by your current schema.

First you have to understand how array on indexes work:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#multikey-indexes

> To index a field that holds an array value, **MongoDB creates an index key for each element in the array**.

This suggests that arrays are not indexed as single objects, but are *unwinded* into multiple objects.

To achieve a similar result to what you want, you may consider using object property maps instead:

```
{
    "path" : "somepath", 
    "verb" : "GET", 
    "switches" : {
        "id": "123",
        "age": "25"
    }
}
```

And create as unique index as usual:

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex({"path": 1, "verb": 1, "switches": 1}, {"unique": true});
```

**However**, this is generally undesirable because querying for the key is non-trivial
[(Also read about this here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589856/mongo-indexing-on-object-arrays-vs-objects).

So alternatively, you can wrap the array within another object instead:

```
{
    "path" : "somepath", 
    "verb" : "GET", 
    "switches" : {
        "options": [
            {
                "name" : "id", 
                "value" : "123"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "age", 
                "value" : "25"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With the same index:

```
db.yourCollection.createIndex({"path": 1, "verb": 1, "switches": 1}, {"unique": true});
```

If you plan to execute queries on the `switches.options` array, this would be the more desirable solution.

Comment: But this fails if the order of elements under options change,

    "options": [
            {
                "name" : "age", 
                "value" : "25"
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "id", 
                "value" : "123"
            }
        ]

won't give duplicate error.

Comment: MongoDB embedded document indices work like embedded document queries, which mean they must match exactly and field orders matters. Add the fact on how multikey indices work, it seems that it is not possible to guarantee uniqueness alone with MongoDB itself if field order cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourDatabase.yourCollection.ensureIndex({"path": 1, "verb": 1, "switches": 1}, {"unique": true})
```

you can use `ensureCollection()` or `createCollection` as you like.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/